# OpenGL + Processing: Rotate and move based on direction

Tags: java, opengl, geometry, processing

I'm trying to rotate and move a triangle into a certain direction, based on the pointing direction of the triangle. In theory, I calculate the sine and cosine of the direction (0-360 degrees) and add these values to the x- and y-position, right? It just doesn't work.

Also, the triangle should point up in the beginning, not down.

```
public void speedUp() {
  float dirX, dirY;
  speed *= acceleration;
  if(speed > 50) speed = 50;
  println("dir: " + direction + " x: " + cos(direction) + " y: " + sin(direction));
  dirX = cos(direction);
  dirY = sin(direction);
  xPos+=dirX;
  yPos+=dirY;
}

public void redraw() {
  GL gl = pgl.beginGL();  // always use the GL object returned by beginGL
  gl.glTranslatef(xPos, yPos, 0);
  gl.glRotatef(direction, 0, 0, 1000);

  gl.glBegin(GL.GL_TRIANGLES);
  gl.glColor4f(0.1, 0.9, 0.7, 0.8);
  gl.glVertex3f(-10, -10, 0);    // lower left vertex
  gl.glVertex3f( 10, -10, 0);    // lower right vertex
  gl.glVertex3f( 0,  15, 0);    // upper vertex
  gl.glEnd();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this right, but you want your triangle to translate towards a direction(x,y) and rotate towards it, right ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you need to convert from polar coordinates(moving about using an angle and a radius) to cartesian coordinates(moving about using the x and y).

The formula looks a bit like this:

```
x = cos(angle) * radius;
y = sin(angle) * radius;
```

So, as @Lie Ryan mentions, you also need to multiply with speed (which is your radius in polar coordinates).

Either have your angle in degrees but use **radians()** when using cos,sin as they work with radians, or use radians, and use **degrees()** with **glRotatef**, up to you

Also, you might want to have a look at glPushMatrix() and glPopMatrix(). Bascially, they allow you to nest transformations. Whatever transformations you do withing the blocks, they affect just that block locally.

Here's what I mean, use w,a,s,d keys:

```
import processing.opengl.*;
import javax.media.opengl.*;

float direction = 0;//angle in degrees
float speed = 0;//radius
float xPos,yPos;

void setup() {
  size(600, 500, OPENGL);
}

void keyPressed(){
  if(key == 'w') speed += 1;
  if(key == 'a') direction -= 10;
  if(key == 'd') direction += 10;
  if(key == 's') speed -= 1;
  if(speed > 10) speed = 10;
  if(speed < 0) speed = 0;
  println("direction: " + direction + " speed: " + speed);
}

void draw() {
  //update
  xPos += cos(radians(direction)) * speed;
  yPos += sin(radians(direction)) * speed;
  //draw
  background(255);
  PGraphicsOpenGL pgl = (PGraphicsOpenGL) g; 
  GL gl = pgl.beginGL();
  gl.glTranslatef(width * .5,height * .5,0);//start from center, not top left

  gl.glPushMatrix();
  {//enter local/relative
    gl.glTranslatef(xPos,yPos,0);
    gl.glRotatef(direction-90,0,0,1);
    gl.glColor3f(.75, 0, 0);
    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_TRIANGLES);
    gl.glVertex2i(0, 10);
    gl.glVertex2i(-10, -10);
    gl.glVertex2i(10, -10);
    gl.glEnd();
  }//exit local, back to global/absolute coords
  gl.glPopMatrix();

  pgl.endGL();
}
```

You don't actually need the { } for the push and pop matrix calls, I added them like a visual aid. Also, you can do this without push/pop, by concatenating your transforms, but it's handy to know those are there for your when you need them. Might come in handy when you want to shoot some GL_LINES out of that triangle...pew pew pew!

HTH

Comment: Thanks. The shooting part was right and will be implemented later. I know it's more like re-inventing the wheel, but I'm using the example to finally play with OpenGL a bit.

Answer (score 5):

You have your units messed up. `glRotatef` excepts **degrees** and the trigonometrical functions expect **radians**. This is the most obvious mistake.

---

Also, `speed` is never used in your snippet. I suppose that every frame you're using it somehow, but in the code you pasted there's:

`xPos+=dirX`

Which is basically "add direction to the position" - not making much sense, unless you want to *"move it exactly 1 unit in the given direction instantenously at the moment when `speedUp()` is called*. The usual approach for continous movement would be to:

```
// each frame:
xPos += dirX * speed * deltaTime;
yPos += dirY * speed * deltaTime;
```

Comment: Ok, I guessed already it would be a radian/degree problem. The speed is left out on purpose as I just want to move 1 unit at the moment. It runs in a loop triggered by the arrow-keys. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

You are obviously new to OpenGl, so I would recommend you, that you look into quaternions to do your roations. Here are two pretty nice article about this matter: [Gamedev](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article1095.asp) and [Nehe](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=Quaternion_Camera_Class). I would recommend you to use the Quaternion class from the JMonkeyEngine. Just remove the savable and some other interfaces and you can use them with ease. Here they are located: [JMonkey Source](http://code.google.com/p/jmonkeyengine/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src/com/jme/math)

I also use the JME math classes for my own projects. I have already striped most of the dependencies and you can download some classes from here: [Volume Shadow](https://github.com/iuiz/VolumeShadow/tree/master/VolumeShadow/src/org/volumeshadow/math/). However the Quaternion class is missing, but you WILL need Vector3f :D.

Comment: Quaternions seem to be a bit of an overkill for 2D, I suppose.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that it was just for 2D :). Yeah, Quaternions are definitely to much for 2D. But your answer should already to the trick :).

Comment: Thanks for the links! I'll try them out. With 31 rep you might be able to post as many links and edit the answer, just to make it complete. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
dirX = speed * cos(direction);
dirY = speed * sin(direction);
```